# Spring batch job executes twice the same decider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to create a job with this flow:

```
execute step1
if (resource doesn't exist)
   execute createStep
else
   execute updateStep
```

I created a decider to return "CREATE" or "UPDATE". My decider is defined with @Service so the bean will be autowired

my job flow is the following:

```
return jobs.get("someJobName")
       .start(step1())
       .next(myDecider).on("CREATE").to(createStep())
       .from(myDecider).on("UPDATE").to(updateStep())
       .end().build();
```

When I run my UnitTest it runs all steps, create and update like it runned the decider second time selecting both paths. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this only occurred in the Unit Tests, I changed the way I run them and now it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me.

Below a single-class working example keeping the same structure to your job flow.

It's not possible on a single run to get the system out message of both `CREATE` and `UPDATE`.

Compare it to your setup and if you are still facing issues please include running code in the description.

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.Random;

@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    MyDecider myDecider() {
        return new MyDecider();
    }

    @Bean
    Step stepInit() {
        return stepFactoryWithMessage("stepInit");
    }

    @Bean
    Step createStep() {
        return stepFactoryWithMessage("createStep");
    }

    @Bean
    Step updateStep() {
        return stepFactoryWithMessage("updateStep");
    }

    @Bean
    Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(stepInit())
                .next(myDecider()).on("CREATE").to(createStep())
                .from(myDecider()).on("UPDATE").to(updateStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    static class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
        public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
            String status;
            if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
                status = "CREATE";
            }
            else {
                status = "UPDATE";
            }
            return new FlowExecutionStatus(status);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    private Step stepFactoryWithMessage(String stepName) {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get(stepName)
                .tasklet(
                        (StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("from " + stepName);
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        }).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I second this answer. Tested and works as expected according to what is asked in the question.

Comment: Yeah. When I run the boot app it runs only one of the tasklets. This only appear when I run in the unit tests.
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()
Any hints on this?